# How do I get the selected values from my dropdown array

Tags: php, html, forms, jquery-ui, drop-down-menu

I am displaying 3 products on a webpage each with their own dropdown select options. I've also given each product its own form.

The product options that I have are unique to each product.

Product_1 options

```
{
   "frame":[
      {
         "template_id":"SKU-26x16-SQUARE",
         "name":"Square Canvas - Small",
         "price":"100",
      },
      {
         "id":3,
         "template_id":"SKU-28x28-SQUARE",
         "name":"Square Canvas - Medium",
         "price":"300",

      },
      {
         "id":3,
         "template_id":"SKU-32x32-SQUARE",
         "name":"Square Canvas - Large",
         "price":"500",
      }
   ]
}
```

Product_2 options

```
{
   "frame":[
      {
         "id":1,
         "template_id":"SKU-16x12-PORTRAIT",
         "name":"Small Portrait Mounted",
         "price":"100",
      },
      {
         "id":2,
         "template_id":"SKU-16x20-PORTRAIT",
         "name":"Medium Portrait Mounted",
         "price":"300",
      },
      {
         "id":3,
         "template_id":"SKU-24x36-PORTRAIT",
         "name":"Large Portrait Mounted",
         "price":"500",
      }
   ]
}
```

Product_3 options

```
{
   "frame":[
      {
         "id":1,
         "template_id":"SKU-11x14-PORTRAIT",
         "name":"Small Portrait",
         "price":"100",
      },
      {
         "id":2,
         "template_id":"SKU-16x20-PORTRAIT",
         "name":"Medium Portrait",
         "price":"300",
      },
      {
         "id":3,
         "template_id":"SKU-24x32-PORTRAIT",
         "name":"Large Portrait",
         "price":"500",
      }
   ]
}
```

Now, the issue is no matter which option I select from the dropdown my form only seems to POST the last option from the list. For example, `product_1` `"name":"Small Portrait"` I need my form to POST all of the items contained within the array `id:1` but it will only POST the values of the last array `id:3`.

Dropdown select containing attributes for each product:

```
<select class="custom-select" id="product-price-{{$i}}-select" name="LeaveType">
    <option selected>Choose a frame...</option>
    @foreach($attributes->frame as $attribute)
        <option
            value="{{$attribute->price}}">{{$attribute->name}}</option>
    @endforeach
</select>
```

Here's the jQuery that updates the dom based on the selected value:

```
   <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('.custom-select').on('change', function () {
                $('.custom-select').not(this).val('Choose a frame...');
                var current = $(this).attr('id');
                var res = current.split("-select");
                $('.' + res[0]).html($(this).val());
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Here's the form again nothing fancy,

```
  <form id="form" action="/" method="POST">
        <input type="hidden" name="product_name" value="{{ $attribute->name  ?? '' }}">
        <input type="hidden" name="sku" value="{{$attribute->template_id ?? ''}}">
        <input type="hidden" name="price" value="{{$attribute->price}}">
        <button id="submit" class="btn btn-success">{{__('Add to cart')}}</button>
    </form>
```

Here's a dump of the POST request although I chose the 1st option the FORM posted the last:

```
array (
  'product_name' => 'Square Canvas - Large',
  'sku' => 'SKU-32x32-SQUARE',
  'price' => '500',
  'size' => '71.49 x 71.49cm',
)
```

Has anyone had this issue before and know a way to solve it? I'm thinking that my array is wrong but would like some advice please.

My question then, does my array of options look ok or should the be nested further? I a user

Comment: post your select attribute

Comment: Added the select attribute, I use a for loop to get a unique id for jquery to update the html element with the value of the selected option which works but posting the form only sends the last item.

Comment: Try to edit select `<select class="custom-select" id="product-price-{{$i}}-select" name="LeaveType[{{$i}}]">`, and add array

Comment: Post your jquery code.

Comment: Looking at the array I'm thinking that it needs to be nested with the name attribute as the parent and then the children in order to get to the correct selected values?

Comment: @user1704524 How do you submit your form? Do you use `ajax`? Please post also your `ajax ` code.

Comment: Not its just a form

Comment: @Bluetree Added the form to the original post

Comment: @user1704524 Can you do a `var_dump($_POST);`. And post the result here after you submit the form.

Comment: @Bluetree I've added the var dump, removed some attributes but the data being sent is complete but for the wrong selection. I chose the 1st option from product_1 but the POST is contains the 3rd option.

Comment: @user1704524 Another question. Where did you put `<select>`? Is it inside of the `form` you posted? And is it before or after the form?

Comment: @Bluetree the select is inside the form

Comment: @user1704524 I posted my answer. You can check it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why you are getting the last option its because you are not updating it when you select an option.

First, we need to add `data` attribute in our options.

```
<select class="custom-select" id="product-price-{{$i}}-select" name="LeaveType">
    <option selected>Choose a frame...</option>
    @foreach($attributes->frame as $attribute)
        <option
            value="{{$attribute->price}}"
            data-template-id="{{$attribute->template_id}}"
            data-name="{{$attribute->name}}"
            data-id="{{$attribute->id}}">{{$attribute->name}}</option>
    @endforeach
</select>
```

Now in your `.custom-select` change event.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.custom-select').on('change', function () {
            $('.custom-select').not(this).val('Choose a frame...');
            var current = $(this).attr('id');
            var res = current.split("-select");
            $('.' + res[0]).html($(this).val());

            // Get the data from selected option
            var selected_option = $(this).find('option:selected');
            var template_id = selected_option.data('template-id');
            var product_name = selected_option.data('name');

            // Now assign it to hidden input field
            $('input[name="product_name"]').val(product_name);
            $('input[name="sku"]').val(template_id);
            $('input[name="price"]').val($(this).val());
        });
    });
</script>
```

That's it. This should solve the problem. I didn't test it. If there's a problem let me know.

One more thing. You can remove the values from this form since it will be populated when you select an option.

Comment: Thanks, I will give this a try now.

Comment: Brillian, thanks for you answer I would never have figured this out on my own.